# Why doesn't this Javascript function work?

Tags: javascript

i would like to be able to click a link and have a form show up. ideally with smoothly maybe use delay?  so far i click on the link and nothing happens.

My Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showForm() {
        document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
```

my HTML

```
<a class="non_link" href="" alt="start a new post" onmouseclick="showForm();">
   Start A New Post
</a>
<form action="#" id="showme" method="post">
```

my CSS

```
#showme {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}
```

took out the # sign and still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is not part of the id:

```
document.getElementById('showme')
```

Additionally, that should probably be `onclick` you're using. Plus, try setting the `href` to something like `href="javascript:void(0);"` (other expressions that return a falsy value should work too afaik).

Comment: been using some jquery so been putting in the #.  took that out but still no dice

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `#` sign in `getElementById`

```
document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
```

You want the id, not the selector.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp).

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` doesn't need the `#` .That's a [jquery standard](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) kept in line with how you define css ids

See MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working in below test HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#showme {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showForm() {      
       document.getElementById('showme').style.display='block';    
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="non_link" href="#" alt="start a new post" onclick="showForm()">
   Start A New Post
</a>
<form  id="showme" method="">
Content of the Form<br/>
Content of the Form
</form>
</body>
</html>
```